# Testing Carrierwave file uploads to s3 with Capybara and Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, amazon-s3, capybara, carrierwave

I've implemented carrierwave file uploads to Amazon s3 just like in [this Railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/383-uploading-to-amazon-s3?view=asciicast).

I'm  having trouble testing this though. I can attach a file with Capybara, but when I click the button to upload it doesn't redirect to the correct action. I checked with save_and_open_page and it's displaying the the homepage instead.

When I test it in the browser it works fine, but the info about the s3 upload does get added to the url ([screenshot](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s3/sh/ef158d64-66c5-482c-ac5a-ec181371f894/f765db2858ba786cd2fdc623d803bad4)). Not sure why this wouldn't work in the test.

Here are some relevant files:

example_spec.rb - https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/1e159f1b93005b8113f2

initializers/carrierwave.rb - https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/924e8755f7c76ecbf5cf

models/work.rb - https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/cfda1a7f15d87dbab731

controllers/works_controller.rb - https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/7fca5f2c81c6cb4de6bc

How can I test this type of form with capybara and rspec?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, I've figured this out. The key is CarrierWaveDirect:

https://github.com/dwilkie/carrierwave_direct#using-capybara

I needed to add this line to my spec_helper.rb:

`include CarrierWaveDirect::Test::CapybaraHelpers`

Then my tests needed these CarrierWaveDirect matchers:

`attach_file_for_direct_upload("#{Rails.root}/spec/support/images/example.jpg")`
`upload_directly(ImageUploader.new, "Upload Image")`

So the final passing test looks like this:

```
it "creates a new work with a test image" do
    client = FactoryGirl.create(:client)
    work = FactoryGirl.build(:work)
    visit works_path
    attach_file_for_direct_upload("#{Rails.root}/spec/support/images/example.jpg")
    upload_directly(ImageUploader.new, "Upload Image")
    fill_in "Name", :with => work.name
    select("2012", :from => "work_date_1i")
    select("December", :from => "work_date_2i")
    select("25", :from => "work_date_3i")
    select(client.name, :from => "work_client_ids")
    fill_in "Description", :with => work.description
    fill_in "Service", :with => work.service
    save_and_open_page
    check "Featured"
    click_button "Create Work"
    page.should have_content("Work was successfully created.")
end
```

I also needed to add this to my initializers/carrierwave.rb:

```
if Rails.env.test?
    CarrierWave.configure do |config|
      config.storage = :file
      config.enable_processing = false
    end
end
```

Rather than mock the response to fog, or test an upload to s3, I just switched off uploads to s3 in the test environment.

Comment: Just a note for anyone that got stuck like me and had everything like this answer. I had to enable js on the test for it to work.